# VTEX tag error - vtex.cmc' is an undeclared prefix

Tags: html, dom, tags

I have a tag vtex in my code and getting this error when I try to update my template:

the tag in my code:

```
<vtex.cmc:ProductQueryStringReferenceShelf layout="d74646-1213-344adc-942-dd19a60555564dd" itemCount="50" columnCount="100" showUnavailable="true"/>
```

**the error: vtex.cmc' is an undeclared prefix;**

anyone know how fix it?

Comment: Are you using vtex CMS? or VTex IO?

Answer (score 0):

So, this error happens because you do not have an imported de XML file that contains the vtex prefix, at the beginning of the HTML document you will have to insert the XML, like this:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:vtex="http://www.vtex.com.br/2009/vtex-common%22%3E />
```

I hope that solves your problem :)